# What is the equivalent of aggregate functions FIRST and LAST from MySQL in Firebird

Tags: sql, firebird

Does anyone know what is the equivalent of the aggregate functions FIRST and LAST from MySQL to Firebird. I have this inventory master table that looks like this:

```
DATE       |ITEM_CODE       | BEG | + | - | - | - | + | + | + | + | - | - | END
2015-10-27 | 000000000MS016 |12.5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 12.5
2015-10-27 | 000000000PN044 |   0 |10 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |   10 
2015-10-27 | 000000000VI064 | 440 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  445 
2015-10-27 | 000000000VI029 | 274 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  269

2015-10-28 | 000000000MS016 |12.5 |20 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 32.5
2015-10-28 | 000000000PN044 |  10 |50 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |   60 
2015-10-28 | 000000000VI064 | 445 | 0 | 0 |10 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  435 
2015-10-28 | 000000000VI029 | 269 | 0 | 0 | 0 |20 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  249

2015-10-29 | 000000000MS016 |32.5 | 0 |10 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |30 | 0 | 5 | 47.5
2015-10-29 | 000000000PN044 |  60 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |   65 
2015-10-29 | 000000000VI064 | 435 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |10 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 8 | 0 |  437 
2015-10-29 | 000000000VI029 | 249 |35 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4 |  280

2015-10-30 | 000000000MS016 |47.5 | 0 |15 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 32.5
2015-10-30 | 000000000PN044 |  65 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 0 |   65 
2015-10-30 | 000000000VI064 | 437 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  437 
2015-10-30 | 000000000VI029 | 280 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 3 | 0 |  273
```

and I have this `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT
  INV.ITEM_CODE,
  FIRST(INV.BEG_QTY) AS BEG_QTY,
  SUM(INV.REC_QTY) AS REC_QTY,
  SUM(INV.RET_QTY) AS RET_QTY,
  SUM(INV.SOLD_QTY) AS SOLD_QTY,
  SUM(INV.BO_QTY) AS BO_QTY,
  SUM(INV.ADJ_QTY) AS ADJ_QTY,
  SUM(INV.COUNT_P) AS COUNT_P,
  SUM(INV.COUNT_C) AS COUNT_C,
  SUM(INV.TRANS_IN) AS TRANS_IN,
  SUM(INV.TRANS_OUT) AS TRANS_OUT,
  SUM(INV.DELIVERY) AS DELIVERY,
  LAST(INV.END_QTY) AS END_QTY
FROM INV_MASTER INV
WHERE (INV.INV_DATE BETWEEN '2015-10-27' AND '2015-10-31')
GROUP BY INV.ITEM_CODE
ORDER BY INV.ITEM_CODE
```

and the result SHOULD look like this:

```
ITEM_CODE      | BEG | + | - | - | - | + | + | + | + | - | - | END    
000000000MS016 |12.5 |20 |25 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |30 | 0 | 5 | 32.5
000000000PN044 |   0 |70 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 0 |   65 
000000000VI064 | 440 | 5 | 0 |10 | 0 |10 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 8 | 0 |  437 
000000000VI029 | 274 |35 |10 | 0 |25 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 3 | 4 |  273
```

but I'm having a problem with the FIRST and LAST aggregate functions, I'm using firebird v2.5. How can i do this?

Comment: FIRST & LAST are not standard because there is no order in a table, only a final result after an outer ORDER BY. What version of SQL do you know them from? What do you expect them to do? Why not use MIN & MAX of DATE?

Comment: @philipxy i just read it somewhere, the FIRST should get the first value it gets from the result (which in my case is the value from the `INV_DATE 2015-10-27`), and the LAST should get the last value (`INV_DATE 2015-10-30`). so what do you think should be my query?

Comment: You still haven't said what "first" and "last" mean clearly. What's "first value", when tables are unordered? Maybe relate it to dates? Is your input ordered in some way and you are appealing to that order? I still can't see what your output is as a function of input. Please finish this sentence: A row <ITEM_CODE,BEG,...,END> belongs in the desired output when ... & ditto for input.

Comment: `DATE **** |ITEM_CODE *****  | BEG | + | - | - | - | + | + | + | + | - | - | END_QTY
 2015-10-27 | 000000000MS016 |12.5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 12.5***
2015-10-28 | 000000000MS016 |12.5 |20 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 32.5***
     2015-10-29 | 000000000MS016 |32.5 | 0 |10 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |30 | 0 | 5 | 47.5***
2015-10-30 | 000000000MS016 |47.5 | 0 |15 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 32.5***` @philipxy let's say i input/query inv_date from `2015-10-27` to `2015-10-31` and i select `FIRST(INV.BEG_QTY)` and  get the sum of others and `LAST(INV.END_QTY)`

Comment: `000000000MS016 | MS RHS 50 X 150 X 3MM X 6M             | LENGTH    | NONE  |` **12.5** `|20 |25 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |30 | 0 | 5 |` **32.5** @philipxy I'm expecting the result to look something like this. the **12.5** is from the first date `2015-10-27` while **32.5** is from the last date `2015-10-30`

Comment: BTW there is no Firebird version 10.3 - the latest stable is 2.5 and version 3 is in beta.

Comment: yea, it's version 2.5 @ain, thanks for that. i confuse it with the crack version. I'm sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to replace the use of `LAST` with

```
(SELECT END_QTY FROM INV_MASTER 
   WHERE ITEM_CODE = INV.ITEM_CODE 
   AND INV_DATE = MAX(INV.INV_DATE)) AS END_QTY
```

This selects the `END_QTY` of the current item, with the highest date for that item.